# moving a rigidbody left and right

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-engine

I can't seem to get my rigidbody to move left and right. The code looks fine and very similar to what everyone else has posted!

The debug statement is getting called but my character is not moving left and right.

Thanks for the help.

```
public float speed = 4.0f;
 void Update()
    {
        float moveDirection = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");

        if (Input.GetKeyDown("d"))
        {
            Debug.Log("pressed d");
            rb.AddForce(new Vector2(Time.deltaTime * speed * moveDirection, 0), ForceMode2D.Force);
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tested it using an 3D environment, but that shouldn't matter.  So after all I'm pretty sure you've got way to less force applied to `AddForce`.

So try increasing `speed` to about `40000`, then you should be able to notice the `AddForce` being applied.

If you want to keep the `speed` value low, you could of course just add a multiplier here:

```
rb.AddForce(new Vector2(Time.deltaTime * speed * moveDirection * 10000f, 0), ForceMode2D.Force);
```

Answer (score 0):

A nice one line option would be to use transform translate.

```
void Update () 
{
    transform.Translate(Vector3.right * speed * Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

AddForce will not work on a Rigidbody which is kinematic. Verify and set **isKinematic** to false in your Rigidbody component. 
If this is already false, trying increasing the force value as suggested by d4Rk.